# Instantaited Rigidbody not changing bodytype

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am dynamically loading GameObjects from a JSON file into the Scene.
I am able to instantiate GameObjects from a prefab, but facing issue changing the RigidBody2d properties.

**Instantiation**

```cs
GameObject greenObj = Instantiate(rotateBouncerObject, 
           new Vector3(gamObj.position.x, gamObj.position.y, 0),     
           Quaternion.Euler(gamObj.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
           gamObj.rotation.eulerAngles.x, gamObj.rotation.eulerAngles.z));
```

The problem I am facing is that when I change the property of RigidBody2D like bodyType it doesn't change. I am changing the bodyType using the code from Kinematic to Dynamic like this.

```cs
greenObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic.
```

When I check in Unity Editor the body type is not updated, but when I log the bodyType it gives me changed bodyType.

Need your inputs on this.

Comment: Are you sure you've just one rigidbody on the gameobject?

Comment: Yes checked that .. there is only one RigidBody . The same code works fine when the gameobject is placed directly in scene instead of Instantiation

Comment: maybe you can try ``greenObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic=false``